# dns lookup only works with DHCP and not with static setup (EtherCard library)

Tags: ethernet

When I use DHCP with `ether.dhcpSetup()` the DNS lookup for NTP `ether.dnsLookup("0.pool.ntp.org")` works fine, but when I use a static setup (because my Android app needs to know the IP address) with `ether.staticSetup(myip);` then this returns false and I don't get an IP address from the NTP pool. How come?

I have an Arduino Nano ATmega328 with a ENC28j60 ethernet shield, and therefore use the EtherCard libray.

Full MWE:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>      // https://github.com/jcw/ethercard
#include <Time.h>           // http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Time

static byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };
static byte myip[] = {192, 168, 2, 106};
const char poolNTP[] PROGMEM = "0.pool.ntp.org"; //pool to get time server from
uint8_t ntpMyPort = 123; //port for the time server, no idea why needed

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);

 //do not forget to add the extra '10' argument because of this ethernet shield
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 10) == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to access Ethernet controller"));
  }

  //static setup
  ether.staticSetup(myip);
  ether.printIp("Address: http://", ether.myip);

 //this works
//  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
//    Serial.println(F("DHCP failed"));

  //Find ip address of a time server from the pool
  if (!ether.dnsLookup(poolNTP)) {
    Serial.println("DNS failed"); //with static setup this line is executed, not so with DHCP
  }
  ether.printIp("Lookup IP   : ", ether.hisip);
}

void loop () {}
```

Comment: I'd suspect gateway IP is not set and DHCP provides it.

Comment: @KIIV As John Burger suggested in his answer that's probably one mistake, but it's not solved yet even with adding dns ip as well (see comment there)

Comment: BTW: why don't you set fixed IP on your DHCP for this device? It could save you these troubles.

Comment: @KIIV Sounds good but what do you mean? The documentation says `dhcpSetup()` doesn't take any parameters, so no way to give it my ip?

Comment: You can set it on your router side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHCP does more than just give you your IP address: it also gives you the Net Mask, the Gateway IP address, and the DNS Server IP address. If you don't call `dhcpSetup()`, you'll have to do it yourself.

According to the `EtherCard` documentation, you can do that as follows:

```
const static uint8_t ip[] = {192,168,0,100}; // Example
const static uint8_t gw[] = {192,168,0,254}; // Example
const static uint8_t dns[] = {192,168,0,1};  // Example

...

if (!ether.staticSetup(ip, gw, dns)
{
    // handle failure to configure static IP address
    // (current implementation always returns true!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know DNS lookup needed more than my ip address. I found my Gateway ip through an ipconfig command (windows), I'm currently searching what the DNS server ip address should be.

Comment: I found the dns ip with doing a DHCP setup and then printing `ether.dnsip`, and when I print it again after the static setup the ip shows correctly but still the dns lookup fails. Any idea what misses more?

Comment: A second look at the documentation solved it! I just had to add the netmask as well, after printing it (after DHCP) with `ether.netmask`.

Answer (score 1):

the documentation of ethercard.h and examples doesn't fit the actual version of *ethercard* very well.

for static ip setup use:

```
ether.staticSetup(myip, gwip, dnsip, netmask);
```

then the dnslookup works. most examples use the old **mymask** name, that is replaced by **netmask**